# How should numbers be aligned in a table column?

Tags: tables, information-architecture, numbers

We have tables that have numbers as data on a few columns. They are **not** currency numbers that add up to a total but **just regular integers**. For example, the number of subscribers.

Should they be center-aligned or right-aligned?

Answer (score 6):

If the user would compare these numbers, then right align helps. Also consider color coding table cells for differnt ranges of numbers so user can quickly scan and identify the ones most relevant to them.